Как совместить опрос и возможность выхода в меню?
@router.message(F.text == text.button_text_nice)
async def choose_person(msg: Message, state: FSMContext):
    await state.set_state(rate_person.person)
    await msg.answer(text.choose_person, reply_markup=kb.choose_person)

@router.message(rate_person.person)
async def rate_person(msg: Message, state: FSMContext):
    await state.update_data(person=msg.text)
    await state.set_state(rate_person.reason)
    await msg.answer(text.why, reply_markup=kb.why)

@router.message(rate_person.reason)
async def done(msg: Message, state: FSMContext):
    await state.update_data(reason=msg.text)
    await state.update_data(account_id=msg.from_user.id)
    data = await state.get_data()
    await msg.answer(text.rate_done, reply_markup=kb.menu)
    await state.clear()

Как сделать так чтобы во время опроса можно было выйти в меню?
